# Object Variable or With block variable not set for Word object

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying using mailmerge from Excel to Word using VBA but I intermittently get an error. I already tried with both true and false, but when its going to different Excel the error will appear.

This code keeps getting error when the VBA is running

```vb
With wdApp
  .Visible = True <<<<<<<<
```

```vb
Sub MailMerge()
'Note: A VBA Reference to the Word Object Model is required, via Tools|References

Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  'Disable alerts to prevent an SQL prompt
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  'Open the mailmerge main document
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:="%%%%", _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .MailMerge
      'Define the mailmerge type
      .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
      'Define the output
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      'Connect to the data source
      .OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, ReadOnly:=True, _
        LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;Data Source=strWorkbookName;" & _
        "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
      End With
      'Excecute the merge
      .Execute
      With wdApp.ActiveDocument
        'What do you want to do with the output document??? For example:
        .SaveAs2 Filename:="&&&&", _
          FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        ' and/or:
        .SaveAs Filename:="^^^^", _
          FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        'Close the output document
        .Close False
      End With
      'Disconnect from the data source
      .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
    End With
    'Close the mailmerge main document
    .Close False
  End With
  'Restore the Word alerts
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
  'Quit Word
  .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If CreateObject fails, your code does not trap the issue and then wdApp will be Nothing and you will get the error you are experiencing.

Comment: It's always a good idea to specify the line where the error occured. Also have a look at [ask] and maybe you also take the [tour]